# Got "Bad request " HTTPS Post request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, post, https

I am trying to send Https post request using NodeJS, but getting back 'Bad request'. At the same time when I send the same request via curl everything is fine. Can you help to fix the Node code:

```
var options = {
       host: 'api.wit.ai',
       port: 443,
       path: '/converse?v=20170611&session_id=125abc&q=Hi',
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
       }
   };
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {...}
```

The curl query:
`curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/converse?v=20170611&session_id=125abc&q=Hi' \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -H "Accept: application/json" \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `http.request()` your post data is not to be sent in the query string.  If you include a query string, it is sent as a query string.  Your post data needs to be sent with `req.write(data)`.  See the code example in [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

Probably your server is returning that error because there is no data in the body of the POST.

Comment: Fixed the problem thought req.write(querystring.stringify({})); previously it was req.write('body');